# PostgreSQL SELECT last array key from text[] array column

Tags: postgresql

How do I `SELECT` only the last key from an array column?

```
SELECT * FROM table;

+----+---------------+
| id | col_array     |
+----+---------------+
| 1  | {"a"}         |
+----+---------------+
| 2  | {"a","b","c"} |
+----+---------------+
| 3  | {"b","d","f"} |
+----+---------------+
```

The desired result for `col_array` would be: a, c, f.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [array_upper](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-array.html)

```
select col_array [array_upper(col_array, 1)] from my_table
```

Comment: Ah, I should have realized arrays had their own functions in PostgreSQL, thanks!